# Aperiodically trigger a thread to run in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

My server aperiodically receives join requests from new clients. Upon receiving a new join request, the server runs a service that can be finished real quick. I implement the service as a Java class (called JC) implementing the Runnable interface. I have parameters within the JC class.

At the caller side, I like to have only one instance (or static) of the JC. My question is how to trigger the run() method in the JC every time. Please show me some code. Thanks.

Hope following edits make sense, which is my current implementation.

In the Server that wants to trigger thread executing:

```
public class Server {
    private static RealService mm = new RealService();
    private static void update(){
      new Thread(mm).start();
    }
}
```

In the Service class:

```
public class RealService implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You show first! Actually, could you please explain what you're trying to do & what you have done so far, possibly with some code examples? Because I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not really clear here, but I would suggest reading about [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) in Java

Answer (score 0):

You could use a socket to listen for incoming requests, the server can spawn a new thread each time there is a request. Once the thread completes, you should intimate the client.
You could read about how a concurrent server works.